# bold issue in latex

Tags: luatex, bold

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc, page, header]{appendix} 
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% Times Roman font
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}% Helvetica, served as a model for arial
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{16}{19}\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}
  {1em}
  {}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{17}\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{17}\sffamily\bfseries\slshape}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{roman}



\begin{document}
\newcounter{rom}


\input{tex/title}\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}

\addtocounter{rom}{1}\setcounter{page}{2}\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}\setcounter{page}{3}

\tableofcontents

\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{tex/abstract}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\input{tex/acknowledgement}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\input{tex/introduction}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\input{tex/litrev}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\input{tex/conclusion}\newpage\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\bibliography{bib/Literature Review}\newpage\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

this is the code i am using in latex. but in pdf output, my chapter heading or section or sub section headings are not bold. What is the issue? How to make these headings bold though i am using {\bfseries}?

Comment: There must be dozens, if not hundreds or even more, versions of a document class called `thesis` available for download from sites on the Internet. Please tell us where you obtained *your* version from.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't provide any sample `\chapter`, `\section`, or `\subsection` directives. I thus doesn't produce the issues you're looking to fix.  Please edit your posting so that it does produce these issues.

Comment: I just took it from net. The issue is how to make it bold, though i have written 'bfseries' for the chapter, section headings.

Comment: "I just took it from net": I'm afraid this is quite unhelpful, as there so many of them "on the net". It may be that your version of `thesis.cls` does something special to sectioning headers. However, we'll never know unless you provide the exact source.

Comment: I have edited the post and now I have given the whole code that i had written.

Comment: I'm afraid your augmented code is even less useful than it was before: it includes lots of `\input` statements to load external files -- but none of the external files. It is now definitely uncompilable.

Comment: I understand but how would I write all the input files here? I have those files and i can compile them but getting a pdf output. The issue remains with the 'bold' headings.

Comment: \chapter{Introduction}
djdjdjdjjvjkjvjkv
\section{Motivation}
jddjkvkvfjkj
\section{Organisation}

this is the sample of a section named introduction.

Comment: http://www.torsten-schoen.de/2013/05/howto-write-a-thesis-using-latex-part-2-getting-started-with-latex/

Comment: I have posted the source and made some changes in the post. Can u pls look into this?

Comment: Please edit your code to replace all `\input` statements with relevant sectioning commands.

Comment: @rajib: Taking something from the internet is not the best solution, especially not for 'thesis templates' in LaTeX. They are wrong often, strange, use absurd commands -- better learn from scratch.

Comment: I followed the link and the template to download does not contain a file `thesis.cls`. And the  template is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix the package `fontenc` and `fontspec`! Use only one of them!
Running `xelatex` or `lualatex` then use `fontspec`. If running `pdflatex` then use `fontenc`:  Here is a working example for `xelatex/lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}% Helvetica, served as a model for arial
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\fontsize{16}{19}\sffamily\bfseries}
{\thechapter}
{1em}
{}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{17}\sffamily\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{17}\sffamily\bfseries\slshape}
{\thesubsection}
{1em}
{}

\begin{document}
\section{A section title}   
foo bar baz

\end{document}
```

You couls use documentclass `scrreprt`, then the headers are bold and sans serif by default. No need then to redfine all those headings.